# false Transaction mined but execution failed

Tags: remix, kovan

I was trying to deploy my smart contract to Kovan test network using Remix IDE,although it compiles successfully but when I try to deploy it I get this error message

"false Transaction mined but the execution failed"

My transactions hash is "[0x1e15c237c4329c63d74f7a3e63e3c9a2b3921d4eaf4bce304baf734a6c35df68](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x1e15c237c4329c63d74f7a3e63e3c9a2b3921d4eaf4bce304baf734a6c35df68)"

The smart contract code is a flattened version of several contracts. see it [here](https://pastebin.com/QWj1NgBA) on a pastebin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a transaction that creates a contract so since it fails the problem is in the constructor.

```
constructor(
    address[] memory _components,
    int256[] memory _units,
    address[] memory _modules,
    IController _controller,
    address _manager,
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol
)
    public
    ERC20(_name, _symbol)
{
    controller = _controller;
    manager = _manager;
    positionMultiplier = PreciseUnitMath.preciseUnitInt();
    components = _components;

    // Modules are put in PENDING state, as they need to be individually initialized by the Module
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _modules.length; i++) {
        moduleStates[_modules[i]] = ISetToken.ModuleState.PENDING;
    }

    // Positions are put in default state initially
    for (uint256 j = 0; j < _components.length; j++) {
        componentPositions[_components[j]].virtualUnit = _units[j];
    }
}
```

The transaction consumes all 10,000,000 gas available. This type of errors is mainly caused by an `assert()` or accessing an array out of bounds.

The constructors are quite simple and there's no assert nor require that might fail (ERC20's constructor is also invoked but it is also quite simple).

The access to arrays `_modules` and `_components` is correct, but access to `_units` never checks against its length. Implicitly the code requires `_units.length == _components.length`.

Parsing the constructor arguments we can see that the last requirements fails. There's one unit and three components.

So this line fails when `j = 1`

```
componentPositions[_components[j]].virtualUnit = _units[j]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, why in my code should I make the modification?

Comment: You can add `require(_components.length == _units.length, "Lengths should match")`, but it is not necesary. If both array parameters have the same length it will work.

Comment: Hi Ismael, Your answer was right. it was because I did not pass enough units to match the components of the constructor argument.